# PostgreSQL column does not exist when it does

Tags: postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL query...

```
WITH update_parts (id,id_finish) 
AS (VALUES (1,42), (2,42), (3,30), (4,30)) 
UPDATE parts SET id = up.id, id_metal = up.id_metal 
FROM update_parts up WHERE up.id = parts.id;
```

...and I get the error...

> column up.id_metal does not exist LINE 1

I have verified I'm connected to the correct database, to the correct table and that the column exists. I'm only partially certain about permissions which I set via the following...

```
GRANT ALL(id_metal) ON parts TO public;
```

...and...

```
GRANT ALL(id_metal) ON parts TO postgres;
```

I plan to limit the permissions to `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` after I've figured out the problem. For clarification it is the "parts" table and the "id_metal" column.

How do I resolve this error and `UPDATE` the rows?

After updating the permissions I'm not sure what else to consider?

I used the following query to get information about the column...

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
AND column_name='id_finish';
```

...which returns...

> Array (
>
> ```
> [table_catalog] => [database name]
>
> [table_schema] => public
>
> [table_name] => parts
>
> [column_name] => id_metal
>
> [ordinal_position] => 7
>
> [column_default] => 
>
> [is_nullable] => YES
>
> [data_type] => bigint
>
> [character_maximum_length] => 
>
> [character_octet_length] => 
>
> [numeric_precision] => 64
>
> [numeric_precision_radix] => 2
>
> [numeric_scale] => 0
>
> [datetime_precision] => 
>
> [interval_type] => 
>
> [interval_precision] => 
>
> [character_set_catalog] => 
>
> [character_set_schema] => 
>
> [character_set_name] => 
>
> [collation_catalog] => 
>
> [collation_schema] => 
>
> [collation_name] => 
>
> [domain_catalog] => 
>
> [domain_schema] => 
>
> [domain_name] => 
>
> [udt_catalog] => [database name]
>
> [udt_schema] => pg_catalog
>
> [udt_name] => int8
>
> [scope_catalog] => 
>
> [scope_schema] => 
>
> [scope_name] => 
>
> [maximum_cardinality] => 
>
> [dtd_identifier] => 7
>
> [is_self_referencing] => NO
>
> [is_identity] => NO
>
> [identity_generation] => 
>
> [identity_start] => 
>
> [identity_increment] => 
>
> [identity_maximum] => 
>
> [identity_minimum] => 
>
> [identity_cycle] => 
>
> [is_generated] => NEVER
>
> [generation_expression] => 
>
> [is_updatable] => YES
> ```
>
> )

Comment: You have `WITH update_parts (id,id_finish)` but you're trying to reference `up.id_metal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going through a lot of hoops with permissions, but the problem is simple syntax:

```
WITH update_parts (id, id_finish) AS (
    VALUES (1,42), (2,42), (3,30), (4,30)
) 
UPDATE parts SET id_metal = up.id_finish
FROM update_parts up WHERE up.id = parts.id;
```

In your CTE you define the columns id and **id_finish** so your main query should refer to the same **up.id_finish**, not the id_metal from the parts table.

Further, it is usless to update `parts.id` with the value of `update_parts.id` because they are the same by definition: `WHERE up.id = parts.id`.

Comment: The `id_finish` and `id_metal` aren't supposed to be there simultaneously, seeing those I realized I had them statically defined in PHP and replaced them with the proper variables. As long as it's all `id_finish` *or* `id_metal` the query works fine. Thanks for your help!